# Create a new dataframe column by comparing two other columns in different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` which contains Alpha 2 country codes (UK, ES, SL etc) and I need these to be the country names. I created a second data frame that has all the Alpha 2 country codes in one column and the corresponding names in another.

I'm trying to compare these two columns then using the index to create the new column. However I am struggling to do this without using a loop. I feel like there is a more efficient way to do this without looping?

I have tried using a for loop, iterating over:

```
cube_data = pd.DataFrame({'Country Code':['UK','ES','SL']})
alpha2 = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['ES','GH','UK','SL'],
               'Name':['Spain','Ghana','United Kingdom','Sierra Leone']})
cube_data
  Country Code
0           UK
1           ES
2           SL

alpha2
  Code            Name
0   ES           Spain
1   GH           Ghana
2   UK  United Kingdom
3   SL    Sierra Leone
```

I have used a for loop to iterate through the columns and when the code from `cube_data` is found in `alpha2['Code']` the index is used to create a new series which has `alpha['Name']` at the correct position corresponding to the cube_data.

end result is:

```
cube_data
  Country Code    Name
0   UK  United Kingdom
1   ES           Spain
2   SL    Sierra Leone
```

Surely there is a better way to do this without looping? I have had a look at `series.isin()` and `series.map()` but these do not seem to provide the result I need.

Can this be done without a loop?

Comment: [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` after converting `alpha2` to a mappable object.

First we make our map:

```
>> country_map = alpha2.set_index('Code')['Name'].to_dict()
>> # country_map = dict(alpha2[['Code', 'Name']].values)
>> # country_map = alpha2.set_index('Code')['Name']
>> print(country_map)
{'ES': 'Spain', 'UK': 'United Kingdom', 'GH': 'Ghana', 'SL': 'Sierra Leone'}
```

Then we map it on the `Country Code` column:

```
>> cube_data['Country'] = cube_data['Country Code'].map(country_map)
>> print(cube_data)
Country Code         Country
0           UK  United Kingdom
1           ES           Spain
2           SL    Sierra Leone
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = alpha2.merge(cube_data, left_on='Code', right_on='Country Code', how='inner').drop('Code', axis=1)
```

`merge` works like an SQL join: here we merge `alpha2` with `cube_data`. We use the columns `'Code'` from `alpha2` and `'Country Code'` from `cube_data` to merge the two datframes together and use an `'inner'` `join` logic meaning that only values present in both dataframes will be kept. Finally we `drop` the column `'Code'` from `alpha2` which contains the same values as the column `'Country Code'`

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [pycountry module](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/)?

I've changed your 'UK' alpha_2 to 'GB'.

```
import pandas as pd
import pycountry

cube_data = pd.DataFrame({'Country Code':['GB','ES','SL']})

for alpha2_code in cube_data['Country Code']:
    c = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2=alpha2_code)
    print(c.name)
```

output:

```
United Kingdom
Spain
Sierra Leone
```

Using a lambda to create new column

```
df = cube_data
df['Name'] = df['Country Code'].apply(lambda x: pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2=x).name)
print(df)
```

output:

```
  Country Code            name
0           GB  United Kingdom
1           ES           Spain
2           SL    Sierra Leone
```